# Access Template variable inside a Promise. [Meteor + Blaze]

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, meteor-blaze

I am using a [navigator.getBattery()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getBattery) utility for the browser to check laptop battery status and it returns a promise. Below is the small example of my code.

**CODE:**

```
Template.Sidebar.onCreated(function(){

    this.isBatteryCharing = new ReactiveVar(0);

    navigator.getBattery().then(function(battery) {

        battery.addEventListener('chargingchange', function(){
          if(battery.charging){
                // access the template variable here. 
                // this.isBatteryCharing.set(battery.charging)
            }
        });

      });
});
```

The Console Error I received is as below :

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
```

How can I access the template variable `this.isBatteryCharing` inside the promise `navigator.getBattery()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to keep the scope:

```
navigator.getBattery().then((battery) => {

    battery.addEventListener('chargingchange', () => {
      if(battery.charging){
            // access the template variable here. 
            // this.isBatteryCharing.set(battery.charging)
        }
    });

  });
```

This way, `this` still refers to your original object.

Comment: Thank you so much!